# How to handle epsilon production in CLR(1) parsing?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr-grammar

Given the following grammar:

1. S -> A
2. A -> AB
3. A -> ϵ
4. B -> aB
5. B -> b

Check whether it is CLR(1) or not.

I have drawn the canonical itemsets as well as the parse table. But I'm not sure whether it is actually correct or not. I have tried searching for some similar examples that have epsilon productions but could not find any. Could someone please help me out?

[image: My solution to this problem]

Comment: ε  is not a symbol, so the last item in I0 is `A -> · , $`. That's a small detail, though. Did you try using your parser to parse some sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial state of your parser is `I0`, and `$` is the only lookahead-terminal for which `I0` has an action. So if the input is anything other than the empty string, your parser will raise an error. But the grammar has non-empty strings in its language. So this can't be a correct parser for the grammar.

I think your main mistake is in propagating lookaheads. For example, when you close `A -> .AB, $`, you need to add `A -> .whatever` items with lookaheads equal to each terminal in `FIRST(B$)`, and you haven't done that.

Comment: Did you mean the productions `A -> .AB` and `A -> .` should have {$, a, b} as their follow?

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean.